# Dialog Problem (result without onclicklistener?)

Tags: android, dialog

Ist there a possibility to do something like that:

```
int selected_value = Dialog("This dialog show a combobox, i want to know which item is selected")
```

Or

```
String typed_chars = Dialog("This Dialog show a TextBox, i want to know the typed chars")
```

It is strongly recommended, that the code will stop while the dialog is shown and resume after dismissing the dialog, like the "showdialogforresult" method in c# or vb.net, I have to show lots of Dialogs and every dialog depends on former choices, I will become crazy if i have to code this with listener or callbacks...

Comment: No, not at all. If you have lots of cascading dialogs, maybe a dialog isn't actually what you want?

Comment: maybe yor're right, i solved it with dialogs in the windows mobile version of the programm, seems to be nessecary to find a other solution for android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't think this is exactly possible like you do it, you do not need to code an anonymous class per Button callback.
Instead you can designate one class that implements `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` and which you specify for all of the buttons. Its `onClick()` callback gets the information about which Dialog was invoked and which button was clicked. So you can operate within this [onClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html#onClick%28android.content.DialogInterface,%20int%29) method with some switch/case or if/else cascades.
Not perfect, but won't make you crazy :)